# Create partial index with SqlAlchemy and Alembic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the following model with the index:

```
class User(TableMixin, Base):
    username = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=False)

    Index('ix_active_username', "active", username,
          unique=True,
          postgresql_where=("active" is True)
          )
```

With the TabbleMixin class

```
class TableMixin():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
```

The index I wish to create in my postgres db:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_active_username on user (username, active) 
where active = True;
```

Active is between quotes because it's not recognized since it's not recognized inside the User class.

After I ran "alembic revision --autogenerate" the alembic file is empty. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: 
All I had to do was put the index outside the scope of the class. And change the where to

```
postgresql_where=(User.active == true())
```

All Code:

```
class User(TableMixin, Base):
    username = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=False)

class TableMixin():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

Index('ix_active_username', User.active, User.username,
      unique=True,
      postgresql_where=(User.active == true())
      )
```

thanks to Ilja Everilä!

Comment: Well, for starters `"active" is True` is just a python expression that evaluates to `False`, which is passed as the argument. Are you creating the `Index` in the class body in `__table_args__`? You could instead create the `Index` separately, which would allow you to access the proper columns through `User` model.

Comment: No I'm not creating it in the __table_args__. I'm creating it in the user class. When I'm trying to create it outside the class I'm getting this error: "'bool' object has no attribute '_compiler_dispatch'"

Comment: You also should not use `is`. It is object identity comparison and cannot be overridden, hence it wouldn't work even if you were using proper sqla constructs. You get the error because you pass `False` as the argument *postgresql_where*, which sqla cannot compile.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "No I'm not creating it in the table_args. I'm creating it in the user class."? Please edit your question to reflect the actual `User` class. It sounds like you've managed to create the index in a way that it is not even bound to the table underlying the model. That's why you don't get an error, but it's also not found by alembic.

Comment: For future reference, if you create the Index the way you now do, it's able to find the table through the bound columns, because the declarative model class is fully created. In the class body the table has not yet been created and so using Index with the columns will not work, as the columns at that point have no idea about the class or the table either. You can instead pass an Index as an argument to the to-be-created table with `__table_args__` in the class body.

Comment: Btw you could self-answer now :). Just move what you wrote under EDIT to an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The complete solution:

```
class User(TableMixin, Base):
    username = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=False)

class TableMixin():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

Index('ix_active_username', User.active, User.username,
      unique=True,
      postgresql_where=(User.active == true())
      )
```